# cannot purge deleted entity in apache atlas

Tags: apache-atlas

I tried to purge deleted entities in apache atlas and I keep getting the following error

"error":"Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 1]"

I am using the following python code. How should I format my json request?

---

> def purgeEntity(guid):
> endpoint = 'http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/admin/purge'
> response = requests.post(endpoint,
> data=guid,
> auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'password'),
> headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}) data = json.dumps({"guid":
> ["0f8aad54-7275-483e-90ca-8b1c09b061bc"]}) purgeEntity(data)

---

Answer (score 0):

curl -iv -u admin:admin -X DELETE http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/3f62e45b-5e0b-4431-be1f-b5c77808f29b

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).